# Angular delete service?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service "MyService" that contains the following:

```
this.myobj = {'dog': 'bark', 'cat': 'meow'}
```

I inject this service into a directive. Within the directive link function I have a $scope.$destroy that does the following:

```
console.log(MyService.myobj);
delete MyService.myobj.dog;
console.log(MyService.myobj);
```

The console.log output looks like after the delete still shows up as:

```
{'dog': 'bark', 'cat': 'meow'}
```

Even though I called the delete on the 'dog' key.
What is going on? Is there a more proper way to delete the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a method to the service that deletes it's properties:

```
var myObj = {
dog: 'bark',
cat: 'meow',
delKey: function (keyName) {
    delete this[keyName];
    }
}
```

Then call the method:

```
MyService.myobj.delKey('dog');
```

If you want to have a method assigned to that service which can operate on any object within that service:

```
myObj: {
            dog: 'bark',
            cat: 'meow'
        },
delKey: function (obj, key) {
            delete this[obj][key];
        }
```

you can check out this plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/f0ousH69sAm3Kdr36kNJ

Comment: Just by way of best practices, I believe this is more appropriate for angular.  You want to maintain a pretty high level of abstraction.  A service should operate on itself by it's own methods, which can then be called by anyone who needs them.

Came across this on a similar post, if it might be useful:
http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: The problem with this is I don't want delKey within myObj as myObj is a part of the service. Ideally if there was a MyService.delKeyFromMyObj('dog') that could do the same, that would be more desirable.